# Why is not variance of normalized data by sklearn equal 1?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scientific-notation

I'm using `preprocessing` from package `sklearn` to normalize data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib3
from sklearn import preprocessing

decathlon = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/Deep-Learning/main/decathlon.txt", sep='\t')
decathlon.describe()

nor_df = decathlon.copy()
nor_df.iloc[:, 0:10] = preprocessing.scale(decathlon.iloc[:, 0:10])
nor_df.describe()
```

The result is

[image]

The mean is `-1.516402e-16`, which is almost 0. On the contrary, the variance is `1.012423e+00`, which is `1.012423`. For me, `1.012423` is not considered as near 1.

Could you please elaborate on this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance `sklearn` and `pandas` calculate `std` differently.

`sklearn.preprocessing.scale`:

> We use a biased estimator for the standard deviation, equivalent to
> `numpy.std(x, ddof=0)`. Note that the choice of `ddof` is unlikely to
> affect model performance.

`pandas.Dataframe.describe` uses `pandas.core.series.Series.std` where:

> Normalized by N-1 by default. This can be changed using the ddof argument
>
> ...
>
> ddof : int, default 1
> Delta Degrees of Freedom. The divisor used in calculations is N - ddof,
> where N represents the number of elements.

It should be noted that, in 2020-10-28, `pandas.Dataframe.describe` does not have a `ddof` parameter so the default of `ddof=1` is always used for `Series`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's clear now. One minor suggestion: `Dataframe.describe` uses `numpy.std(x, ddof=1)`, not `numpy.std(x)`.

Comment: @LAD I couldn't find a direct reference to `ddof=1` in the [`pandas.DataFrame.describe` source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L9891).

Comment: This is because `numpy.std(x)` by default uses `ddof=0`.

Comment: @LAD I updated the answer with direct references to source/docs.

Comment: Thank you so mich for your help.